# How can I plot an intersection of two figures from fimplicit3 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, plot, intersection, implicit

I asked it on mathworks as well but still no any replies there, so probalby someone around here will help me.

I have two implicit functions of three variables. I plotted two surfaces using fimplicit3 in Matlab (it appeared with R2016b matlab). Then I want to intersect them and to visualize the result. How can I do it? Could anybody help please?

For example

```
f = @(x,y,z) x.^2 - y^3 + z^2 - 4; 
fimplicit3(f);
grid on; hold on;
f = @(x,y,z) x.^4 + y.^3 - 0.005.*z.^2 + 0.3.*cos(x) + exp(y) + 2.3.*exp(z);
fimplicit3(f);
```

Comment: [This mathworks post](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93623-how-do-i-plot-the-line-of-intersection-between-two-surfaces) may be helpful for you. As an alternative, you can try a symbolic solver.

Comment: @m7913d Yeah, I've seen it but my case is the third in the post what the author said about intersection of two implicit surfaces I didn't really understand

Comment: Your problem can be easily transformed into case 2. The first function can be made explicit: `z = x.^2 - y`

Comment: @m7913d Sorry, that was my typo. I corrected it now. So I still can't make it explicit..

Answer (score 1):

One can transform your problem numerically to [case 1 of this mathworks post](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93623-how-do-i-plot-the-line-of-intersection-between-two-surfaces), using [fsolve](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html).

```
% definition & plotting of the implicit function
f1 = @(x,y,z) x.^2 - y.^3 + z.^2 - 4; 
H1 = fimplicit3(f1);
grid on; hold on;
f2 = @(x,y,z) x.^4 + y.^3 - 0.005.*z.^2 + 0.3.*cos(x) + exp(y) + 2.3.*exp(z);
H2 = fimplicit3(f2);

% solve both function for a desired meshgrid
[x, z] = meshgrid(linspace(-2, 2, 20), linspace(-2, 2, 20));
y1 = fsolve(@(y) f1(x, y, z), -2*ones(size(x)));
y2 = fsolve(@(y) f2(x, y, z), zeros(size(x)));

% apply case 1 of the mathworks post
ydiff = y1 - y2;
C = contours(x, z, ydiff, [0 0]);
xL = C(1, 2:end);
zL = C(2, 2:end);
yL = interp2(x, z, y1, xL, zL);
line(xL, yL, zL, 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

[image]

**Extra explanation**

- I created a x-z mesh, instead of a x-y mesh, because f1 is not a function in the x-y plane, i.e. an (x, y)-point  corresponds with multiple z-values, which is not the case for an (x, z) point.
- Note that is may be beneficial to implement case 2 instead, because then you only need to apply `fsolve` for one of the implicit functions.
- I transformed `f1` to allow vectorised evaluation, i.e. use `.^` instead of `^`.
- `y1 = fsolve(@(y) f1(x, y, z), -2*ones(size(x)));`: solves the function `f1 == 0` to `y` for every given combination of (x, z) with the same initial guess of -2 for every (x, z) point.
- *Choice of initial guess:* look at the plotted graph an estimate a good start value. If `fsolve` doesn't find a solution try a better/other start value. `f1` get stuck starting from zero due to the flat region at that point.
- *Choice of meshgrid plane:* search a plane in which the solution is unique, because `fsolve` will only return one value.

**Old problem (f1 is slightly different)**

For your specific problem, the best method is to transform your problem to [case 1 of this mathworks post](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93623-how-do-i-plot-the-line-of-intersection-between-two-surfaces). The first function can be made explicit: `z = x.^2 - y`

In general, one can evaluate every implicit function for a specific grid (x, y) using a numerical solver as follows:

```
% definition & plotting of the implicit function
f1 = @(x,y,z) x.^2 - y + z; 
H1 = fimplicit3(f1);
grid on; hold on;
f2 = @(x,y,z) x.^4 + y.^3 - 0.005.*z.^2 + 0.3.*cos(x) + exp(y) + 2.3.*exp(z);
H2 = fimplicit3(f2);

% solve both function for a desired meshgrid
[x, y] = meshgrid(linspace(-4, 4, 40), linspace(-5, 0, 40));
z1 = fsolve(@(z) f1(x, y, z), zeros(size(x)));
z2 = fsolve(@(z) f2(x, y, z), zeros(size(x)));

% apply case 1 of the mathworks post
zdiff = z1 - z2;
C = contours(x, y, zdiff, [0 0]);
xL = C(1, 2:end);
yL = C(2, 2:end);
zL = interp2(x, y, z1, xL, yL);
is = zL > H2.ZRange(1);
line(xL(is), yL(is), zL(is), 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but I corrected my typo now. And with this correction it doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: also I didn't understand these parts of the above code:z1 = fsolve(@(z) f1(x, y, z), zeros(size(x)));  & xL = C(1, 2:end);
yL = C(2, 2:end);

Comment: I edited my answer and tried to make it more clear. See also the `fsolve` documentation and the mathworks post. Note that `xL = C(1, :);` will probably also work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, now I understand it more. But still you're using the special form of the given functions. But what can I do in a case where f1 may look like exp(y^2) - sin(x^3) + cos(z^4) and f2 is something complicated as well? The second question is why you give "-2*ones(size(x))" to the first fsolve? Really don't get this moment and what determines your choice of initial point to the fsolve. Couldn't you explain it please?

Comment: As pointed out further in the post, you should look at your graph and try to assist Matlab (fsolve) as much as needed.

Comment: But you don't get it? I suggest to try it yourself with the newly suggested `f1` function. Note that the tricky part is `fsolve` and if you use case 2 of the mathworks post, you only have to use `fsolve` once, which may give you a more general solution.

Comment: to be honest, yeah, I can't completely understand it. I understand that we create a rectangular grid. Our aim is to go through the nodes and to find a solution of f(x,y,z) = 0, considering x(i,j) and y(i,j) as fixed points, so in fact we obtain a function of one variable F(z). We use these nodes as initial points when solving the nonlinear equation F(z) = 0. But what happens next I don't clearly understand.

Comment: the next moment I don't understand is how to choose what function to put in fsolve. Cause if I have, say, f1 = exp(y^2) - sin(x^3) + cos(z^5) and f2 = sin(cos(x*y)) - z^exp(y) then how should I choose it? What should I take into consideration? Of course I randomly created these f1 and f2 right now but anyway. I would like to get an idea of it :-). And also I don't understand this interpolation. Why are we doing it and what for?

Comment: Probably there's a sense in creating a function like f(x,y,z) = f1(x,y,z) - f2(x,y,z). And then make a rectangular grid on, say, (y,z) and then to find solutions of F(x) = 0 and then to use it somehow? Can't get the puzzle

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to see it as a 1D function F(z). Using `fsolve`, I calculate in the region of interest (defined by the meshgrid) a whole bunch of (x, y, z) points, which obey the implicit function `f1(x, y, z)==0`. I could use these points to plot the function similarly to what fimplicit does: `surface(x, y1, z);`. So, (x, y1, z) is the numerical representation of `f1 == 0`.

Comment: If you take another function, you may need to adapt the meshgrid to the location where the intersection occur and eventually the meshgrid plane. You may need to change the initial guess if fsolve is unable to find a solution.

Comment: An intersection occur, when (x, y, z) are the same for both functions. So, if x and z are the same, intersection occur when `ydiff = y1 - y2 = 0`. Because we evaluated the function at discrete points, this will never be exactly true, therefore we use contours which will interpolate the `ydiff` values to calculate to calculate the zero crossings and will return the corresponding interpolated (x, z) values. To calculate the z values, we should interpolate (x, y1, z) (or (x, y2, z)) for a given (x, z) to obtain y1 and y2, which are the same at these intersection points.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I need some time to think through it. If any questions appear I'll ask you if you don't mind :-)